# Filled partial empty column with value based on another column ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm not sure my title is clear. Sorry about that. I have the following table :

```
ID           ref.    dummy_metrics dummy_dimensions
6091039909   A       123           foo
5914111836   B       456           bar
6538463041   C       789           foobar
6018474808   D       1010          bar
6091039909                         foo
6091039909                         foo
6538463041                         foobar
6538463041                         foobar
6538463041                         foobar
```

As you can see some part of my table are empty. I would like to make sur that the `ref.` column is always filled with something. And I want this value to be based on the `ID<>ref.` key-pair combination.

So here is my expected output :

```
ID           ref.    dummy_metrics dummy_dimensions
6091039909   A       123           foo
5914111836   B       456           bar
6538463041   C       789           foobar
6018474808   D       1010          bar
6091039909   A                     foo
6091039909   A                     foo
6538463041   C                     foobar
6538463041   C                     foobar
6538463041   C                     foobar
```

I don't want to have to build a pre-defined look-up table like I could do using the `CASE` formula. I want something dynamic for every `ID<>ref.` key-pair combination I can found in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty simple method:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(t.ref,
                max(t.ref) over (partition by dummy_dimensions),
                max(t.ref) over ()
               ) as imputed_ref
```

This uses window functions to fill in the missing values.  Note that there are two levels of imputation -- one based on `dummy_dimensions` and the other based on the whole table (in case the dimension `ref` values are all `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* subquery:

```
select ID, 
      coalesce(ref,  (select ref 
                      from table t1
                      where t1.ID = t.ID
                      )
              ) as ref, 
       dummy_metrics, dummy_dimensions
from table t;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? I'm lost because of the sub-query.